# CherryPy - saving checkboxes selection to variables

Tags: python, cherrypy, checkbox

I'm trying to build a simple webpage with multiple checkboxes, a Textbox and a submit buttom.

I've just bumped into web programing in Python and am trying to figure out out to do it with CherryPy.

I need to associate each checkbox to a variable so my .py file knows which ones were selected when clicking the 'Start button'.
Can someone please give some code example ?
Do I have any advantage including some Python Javascript Compiler like Pyjamas?

```
<form action="../remote_targets/ssh_grab.py">
  <label for="goal"><strong>Host Availability:</strong></label>
  <input style="margin-left: 30px;" type="checkbox" name="goal[]" value="cpu" /> CPU idle<br>
  <input style="margin-left: 30px;" type="checkbox" name="goal[]" value="lighttpd" /> Lighttpd Service<br>
  <input style="margin-left: 30px;" type="checkbox" name="goal[]" value="mysql" /> Mysql Service<br>
</form>
```

Thanks !

Comment: the `"foo[]"` style for list form items is an artifact of Ruby on Rails.  Such names will automagically be collected into a list, though names like `"foo"` would be left as scalar values.  I nice convenience, but completely external to either HTML forms or HTTP, and not widely implemented in any other web framework, in python or otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's a minimal example:

```
import cherrypy

class Root(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def default(self, **kwargs):
        print kwargs
        return '''<form action="" method="POST">
Host Availability:
<input type="checkbox" name="goal" value="cpu" /> CPU idle
<input type="checkbox" name="goal" value="lighttpd" /> Lighttpd Service
<input type="checkbox" name="goal" value="mysql" /> Mysql Service
<input type="submit">
</form>'''

cherrypy.quickstart(Root())
```

And here is the terminal output:

```
$ python stacktest.py 
[10/Sep/2010:14:25:55] HTTP Serving HTTP on http://0.0.0.0:8080/
CherryPy Checker:
The Application mounted at '' has an empty config.
Submitted goal argument: None
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2010:14:26:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "" "Mozilla..."
Submitted goal argument: ['cpu', 'mysql']
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Sep/2010:14:26:15] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 276 "http://localhost:8003/" "Mozilla..."
[10/Sep/2010:14:26:26] ENGINE <Ctrl-C> hit: shutting down app engine
[10/Sep/2010:14:26:26] HTTP HTTP Server shut down
[10/Sep/2010:14:26:26] ENGINE CherryPy shut down
$
```

As you can see, CherryPy will collect multiple controls with the same name into a list. You don't need the `[]` suffix to tell it to do that. Then, iterate over the list to see which values were submitted. (Keep in mind that, if only one item is selected, then the `goal` argument will be a single string instead of a list!)

Comment: You're a saint!
I'd vote on your answer if I already had the points.
Thanks for pushing me into the right direction.
I've mostly got the thing up and running,
I'm also using 'argument_name'.length to safeguard against your
"if only one item is selected, then the goal argument will be a single string instead of a list" warning.

Now I'll need to decipher how to embed some basic CSS into it (which I still know zero :)
)  
Can anyone point me to some little projects examples in CherryPy like this one?
I haven't been able to google nothing more than the vanilla 'Hello world!'/'basic blog' examples

Comment: About, "'argument_name'.length" Actually I've ended up using type(argument_name) to differentiate how to extract the data