# How to collect values from checkbox in App Engine (python)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, checkbox

I found an [article for CherryPy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686773/cherrypy-saving-checkboxes-selection-to-variables) and some [articles](http://www.plus2net.com/javascript_tutorial/checkbox-array.php) on how to do this with Javascript, but is there a way to collect values from checkbox with `webapp`? Thanks.

My naive attempt to append the `<...name="article_tag"...>` from the form to a list fails because it only writes the first checked item (in this case "sputnik"):

```
K = []
for i in range(1,5):
    K.append(self.request.get("article_tag"))
    self.response.out.write(K)
    logging.info("""*****K %s""" % K)
```

logging.info:

```
*****K [u'sputnik', u'sputnik', u'sputnik', u'sputnik']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer: 
http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/requestclass.html#Request_get_all

```
K = self.request.get_all("article_tag")
```