# checkbox values in cherrypy

Tags: python, checkbox, cherrypy

I understand that Cherrypy makes checkbox values available as a list cfg question ([CherryPy - saving checkboxes selection to variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686773/cherrypy-saving-checkboxes-selection-to-variables))

Let's say I have following form data:

```
... snip ...
<input type=checkbox id="1">
<input type=checkbox id="1">
<input type=checkbox id="1">

<input type=checkbox id="2">
<input type=checkbox id="2">
<input type=checkbox id="2">

<input type=checkbox id="3">
<input type=checkbox id="3">
<input type=checkbox id="3">
... snip ...
```

Then Cherrypy makes this available as:

```
{'1': [u'on', u'on', u'on'],'2': [u'on', u'on', u'on'],'3': [u'on', u'on', u'on']}
```

From the moment I uncheck the second checkbox id3 then I get:

```
{'1': [u'on', u'on', u'on'],'2': [u'on', u'on', u'on'],'3': [u'on', u'on']}
```

With this I'm unable to say which checkbox is unchecked, .... I could when 'off' would be used when a checkbox is unchecked.. but that's not the case.

Any ideas how to tackle this?

Cheers,

Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a nit: The "id" attribute in HTML is supposed to be unique for the whole document.

You then have two options:

1. Change the "name" attributes to be unique, like `<input type="checkbox" name="3b">`, in which case you'll get back `{..., '3a': u'on' '3c': u'on'}`, or
2. Make the values unique, like `<input type="checkbox" name="3" value="b">`, in which case you'll get back `{..., '3': [u'a', u'c']}`.

Comment: I was afraid that it was going to boil down to this.  I'll go for option 1.  Thanks!